# PHP wont connect to Azure SQL DB with mssql_connect

Tags: php, azure-sql-database, cpanel

I need to connect to an Azure SQL DB from an external PHP app on shared cPanel hosting.

My host has enabled mssql_connect but wont enable MS's recommended sqlsrv_connect in the shared environment.

I have whitelisted the webserver IP in Azure's Portal, and whitelisted the DB  address in cPanel.

The test script seems to try to connect, but cant. No error information is provided: http://app.hivve.com.au/api/

PHP is:

```
$db_server = "cjweb.database.windows.net:1433"; // update me
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";

$conn = mssql_connect($db_server, $db_username, $db_password);

print_r(mssql_get_last_message());
```

Has anyone else been down this road? My host wont provide anymore assistance so Im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to connect as shown below? Please look at the user name.

Add [aftermath] on the ~/.freetds.conf:

```
[aftermath]
    database = mydatabase
    host = cjweb.database.windows.net
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0


$myServer = "aftermath"
$myUser = cjweb@cjweb
$myPass = your_password

$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
```

Comment: I can't edit the .conf file in a shared environment.

Answer (score 0):

What I found in Azure SQL document [Quickstart: Use PHP to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-php) that maybe you have lost the "UID" agrument.

```
<?php
    $serverName = "your_server.database.windows.net"; // update me
    $connectionOptions = array(
        "Database" => "your_database", // update me
        "Uid" => "your_username", // update me
        "PWD" => "your_password" // update me
    );
    //Establishes the connection
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
?>
```

You can first test Alberto Morillo's code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sqlsrv_connect is disabled.